# Which should I use: LINQ or PLINQ

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0, plinq

PLINQ automatically parallelizes local LINQ queries. PLINQ has the advantage of being easy to use in that it offloads the burden of both work partitioning and result collation to the Framework.

In general programming which should I user simple LINQ or PLINQ?

Is PLINQ is better to user for too large data? or also better for small data??

Comment: I guess maybe you found this thread, but in case if not , i'll recomend you to read the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8547903/896258

Comment: I would recomend also that link. (It's a very short example). It depends not on how large Data you have, but how much time will take other threads to resolve the main linq request.  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/374420/When-to-use-PLINQ-vs-LINQ